# Am I using the terminology of group theory correctly?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, terminology

I'm attempting to learn some group theory. Is the following correct (both in terms of terminology and the validity of the conclusions written in bold)?

> Define the abelian group (which is the symmetry group of some geometric object)
>   $$(G,+)=\{0,x,y,z,x+y,x+z,y+z,x+y+z\},$$
>   where $x,y,z$ are reflections and thus of order $2$. Because of their order, the identity, $0,$ is any of $x+x,y+y,z+z.$ For these reasons, **$\bf{\{x,y,z\}}$ is the generating set of $G.$** Because $G$ is abelian and of order $8,$ $G$ is isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z}_8,$ $\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2,$ where $\oplus$ denotes the direct sum. But since $G=(0,x)\oplus(0,y)\oplus(0,z),$ **$\bf{G}$ must be isomorphic to the latter of the three.**

That is, am I using the concepts/terminology correctly and are the conclusions written in bold correct given the definition of $G$? Furthermore, my second conclusion seems very vague (it is not clear in my head either) - if it is true, how can it be made more rigorous?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if we want to be rigorous then you can't define an element of $G$ as $x+y$. That's because $+$ is a function on $G$, so you need to have $G$ first. You have a circular reference here. So normally you would do

$$G=\{0,x,y,z,a_1,a_2,a_3, a_4\}$$

and then you define $+$ as

$$x+y=a_1$$
$$x+z=a_2$$
$$y+z=a_3$$
$$...$$

But your definition can obviously be understood as a shortcut (even though with such approach it might be harder to prove that $G$ is a group).

---

Now for the second part you use $\oplus$ symbol with two different meanings. So let's be rigorous here as well. $G \oplus H$ is a direct sum of groups $G, H$, defined as the set of pairs $(g, h)\in G\times H$ together with pointwise group multiplication/addition.

Also if $G$ is an abelian group and $A_1,\ldots, A_n\leq G$ then define

$$A_1+\cdots+A_n=\{a_1+\cdots+a_n\ |\ a_i\in A_i\}$$

It follows that the set above is a subgroup of $G$. Now we have the following lemma

> Let $G$ be an abelian group and $A_1,\ldots,A_n\leq G$. If $G=A_1+\cdots +A_n$ and for any $i$ we have $$A_i\cap (A_1+\cdots+A_{i-1}+A_{i+1}+\cdots+A_n)=0$$ then $G\simeq A_1\oplus\cdots\oplus A_n$.

Note that in one place I use equality (of sets) $=$ symbol while in the other isomorphism (of groups) $\simeq$ symbol.

This explains why $G=\{0,x\}+\{0,y\}+\{0,z\}$ **must** be isomorphic to the direct sum $\{0,x\}\oplus\{0,y\}\oplus\{0,z\}$. And each one of those groups is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (being of prime order $2$) and thus the final answer is $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Note that you don't even need the fact that "$G$ is of order $8$ so it has to be one of the $3$ possible abelian groups of order $8$".

---

So yeah, except for my nitpicking your reasoning is correct. :)

Comment: Thank you! By $A\leq G,$ do you mean that $|A|\leq |G|$? Also, I don't quite understand your second to last paragraph, "Note that you don't even..." - could you elaborate? Lastly, is it also true that $\{x,y,z\}$ is the generating set of $G$?

Comment: @Lovsovs Oh, sorry, $A\leq G$ usually denotes "$A$ is a subgroup of $G$", so it is analogous to $A\subseteq G$ except we also want $A$ to be closed under group operation and inverse.

Comment: As for the second question: you say "$G$ is order $8$ so it is either $\mathbb{Z}_8$, $\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$". You don't need that. The whole proof is correct if you remove that remark.

Comment: And finally yes $\{x, y, z\}$ is a set of generators.